# update mysql with jQuery.ajax and then locate to page

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery-mobile, window.location

I'm building an app with phonegap and jQuery mobile. In my app I have a button that updates mysql and after success locates to different page. When I press the button mysql gets updated, but browser doesn't locate to different page, so I guess function doesn't success? This is the code I use, is there some problems with it or why doesn't the `window.locate` work even though the update part does?

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="detailsPage" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
  <div data-role="content"> 
      <input type="button" id="button_id" value="UPDATE" data-theme="b" onClick="UpdateRecord();">
      <input type="button" id="button_id" value="DELETE="d" onClick="DeleteRecord();">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```js
<script>  

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

function UpdateRecord(update_id) {
        var id = getUrlVars()["id"]; 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: serviceURL + "update.php", 
            data: 'id='+id , 
            cache: false, 
            success: function(response) 
            {
                window.location = "list.html"
            }
        });
}

function DeleteRecord(update_id) {
        var id = getUrlVars()["id"]; 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: serviceURL + "delete.php", 
            data: 'id='+id , 
            cache: false, 
            success: function(response) 
            {
                window.location = "list.html"
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the update.php:

```php
<?php
include 'config.php';
// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
// new data
$id = @$_POST['id'];
// query
$sql = "UPDATE table
        SET number=3
        WHERE IND=?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($id));
?>
```

Comment: try to change this var id = getUrlVars()["id"]; as var id = getUrlVars()[update_id];

Comment: that won't work. geturlvars gets id from URL so if i put update_id there it has nothing to get because there is no update_id in the url

Comment: window.location = "list.html" add a semicolon.

Comment: like this: window.location = "list.html"; ? doesn't work

Comment: are you sure your updation query running correctly? Please debug in console if there is any error coming in jquery. please run your ajax file directly to check whether any error in that file.Thanks

Comment: firebug's console shows it red with a little x mark so there is some errors. But how can i figure out what the error is? it doesn't give any error messages

Comment: can you post the whole file so that we can get what the exact problem is?

Comment: I posted the whole file, please see my update

Comment: where is your jquery file ,include <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script> in your html

Comment: I have add above jquery link removed serviceURL + and its working, Please speicfy serviceURL value I think this will work.

Comment: jquery is linked in the previous page because i have made the website with jquery mobile and it loads new pages with ajax. So that is not the problem. And i cant remove serviceURL, because update.PHP is in external server and it has to be saved to variable

Comment: Then please give a value to your serviceurl, like var serviceURL ='Your url'; in top of your script.

Comment: serviceurl is not the problem. It is saved to localStorage and if it can update the mysql on external server then it works. The problem is in somewhere else. Even if i put my url directly to code it wont work

Comment: It will be interesting to see how will you solve this.Sorry but I think i may not help you here.